# Did a bunch of corners get rounder recently?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, design

For some reason things look different to me since yesterday-ish. Corner rounding radii seem to have increased...

- The focus outline for the question authoring UI's title field and tags field
- The focus outline for the comment input field
- The shape of topbar items, as visible when hovering and the background colour changes

Did the SE stylesheets change? Did my user agent's default stylesheet change in a way that affected SO? (I hope not. I really think I'd have noticed this on other sites if that'd happened.) Has it always just been like this?

Comment: Yea, looks like it. (Whether "it" is "crazy" or "rounding" is up to you :D)

Comment: Stack Overflow was rough, it is now more smooth, with its edges rounded.

Comment: SE is just trying to cut corners where it can.

Comment: *"Am I crazy or did a bunch of corners get rounder recently?"* - I have bad news. One does not exclude the other.

Comment: Definitely been an update, and it works like crap on mobile. SMH. The fact that the de facto Q&A site for programming is destroying mobile usability (app long dead, site breaking) is very sad.

Answer (score 23):

Rounded corners did not change. The [focus state changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398704/new-focus-styles-updates-styling-for-button-groups) for accessibility purposes.

Answer (score 12):

I had a tab open from before. Here is a comment box. rev 2024.2.8.4531:

[image: Comment text box before a UI change]

Here is the comment box in rev. 2024.2.14.4854:

[image: Comment text box after a UI change]

Comment: do you have the SE site rev number from the old tab to compare to the current one? any browser update in between?

Comment: No browser update - I can't *close* the browser to update it or I won't have the old state :P The revision is 2024.2.8.4531

Comment: Current rev is `2024.2.14.4854` so an update seems to indeed have been rolled out.